# How to use react leaflet context?

Tags: react-leaflet

I'm trying to access the react leaflet context, but I don't understand how it works

Here is what I tried :

```
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup, LeafletContext } from 'react-leaflet';

...

render() {
    <Map 
        center={position} 
        zoom={zoomInit}
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        ref={this.mapRef}
        whenReady={this.mapReady}
    >
    <TileLayer id='id' accessToken='accessToken' attribution="attribution" url="url"/>
    <LeafletContext.LeafletConsumer>
        {
            map => console.log(map)
        }
    </LeafletContext.LeafletConsumer>
    </Map>
```

I'd like to know how to import LeafletContext ?

And then I'd like to understand how to get map reference ?

I want to access it because doc says it gives access to map. I've tried to access map thru react ref but the avaibility is somewhat random.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    setTimeout(this.test, 1000)
}


componentDidMount () {
    console.log(this.mapRef.current); // undefined

}


mapReady = () => {
    console.log(this.mapRef) // undefined
}

test() {
    console.log(this.mapRef.current.leafletElement) // Ok, shows map object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [react-leaflet documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/context.html)

> The context provider and consumer are exported as `LeafletProvider` and `LeafletConsumer`

You need to import `LeafletConsumer` (not LeafletContext)

```
import { LeafletConsumer } from 'react-leaflet';
```

Also, the context object has the following shape

```
type LeafletContext = {
  map?: Map,
  pane?: ?string,
  layerContainer?: ?LayerContainer,
  popupContainer?: ?Layer,
}
```

So you need to use it like this in your render method

```
<LeafletConsumer>
  {context => console.log(context.map)}
</LeafletConsumer>
```